# Limit of the Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, soft-question, riemann-integration

A week ago my professor introduced us to the Riemann integral and said that we will use the graphic intuition that it calculates the area under a curve. He also said that the Riemann integral doesn't really define what the general area under a curve is and that we therefore need a theory of measurement (measure theory, I presume and as a generalisation of the Riemann integral the Lebesgue integral?). But I thought the whole point of the Riemann integral was to get a general definition for an area by using rectangles as approximations for the area because you can calculate those easily. What did I not understand? Why is measure theory necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A lot of functions, it turns out, are not Riemann integral, like for instance the characteristic function on the non-rationals. But when you develop the Lebesgue integral, many of these functions become integrable, hence measure theory makes a lot more functions integrable, to say it simply

Comment: @Norse So the Lebesque Integrall is a generalization of the Riemann Integrall, roughly speaking. Or can they yield different result to the same function (under the presumption that it is riemann integretable).

Comment: Well, some functions are improper Riemann integrable but not Lebesgue integrable, but there are some results on when one implies the other. But if the function is both Riemann and Lebesgue integrable, they yield the same result.

Answer (score 2):

The Lebesgue integrable functions on $[a,b]$ include the (proper) Riemann integrable functions and much much more. But the fact that we can integrate more functions is not the real reason measure theory is important. The real reason is it simply works better theoretically. For example "convergence theorems": If $f_n\to f$ pointwise and [some extra condition] then $\int_a^b f_n\to \int_a^b f$: With the Lebesgue integral we can give much better theorems of this form, with weaker extra conditions.

### The Difference

An analogy, meant to illustrate the difference and why the Lebesgue integral "should" work better: Say you have  a large nummber of  people in a room. Each person has an age, which is a positive integer less than 100, and  you want to find the sum of all the ages. Which procedure seems likely more efficient and accurate?

(i) You say $s=0$ at the start, go through the crowd one person at a time, adding each person's age to $s$.

(ii) You have everyone of age $1$ to raise their hands; you count, and record $n_1$ as the number of people aged $1$. Similarly you count $n_2$, the number of age $2$, etc., and then you calculate $n_1+2n_2+\dots+99 n_{99}$.

Seems clear to me that (ii) is a better idea. This is the difference between the two integrals; the Riemann integral uses an approximation analogous to  (i), while the Lebesgue integral  uses an approximation analogous to (ii).